# Convert QSetting value to StdString

Tags: c++, string, qt, ini

Currently, I have a datum saved, at ini file,  it is used a QSetting class. I wonder, how I could convert it to std::string without using qt. Does anyone know how to determine the code and how decodec?

My Data:

```
 dataID="\x1\0\0\0\xd0\x8c\x9d\xdf\x1\x15\xd1\x11\x8cz\0\xc0O\xc2\x97\xeb\x1\0\0\0Z\xa3\xa3\xc9\x18\xb5>M\xa9=)\xb4\xda\xfb{\xfe\x4\0\0\0\x2\0\0\0\0\0\x3\x66\0\0\xc0\0\0\0\x10\0\0\0|\x16>\x17\x96\xda\xc4-O\xe9\x1f!\\\aAW\0\0\0\0\x4\x80\0\0\xa0\0\0\0\x10\0\0\0\x45\xf4K\x9e\xc2k$\f\xd2\xcbK\b\xf4\xd3\xdf}(\0\0\0\xb2\xb2\xf1\x13[sy\r\xeb\xa7\x96l\x8d\xd7\xa4\xccJ\xf6M\xc1\xf3U3W\xe4\xf7\xa6\x1a\x86s`v\xc2\x8d\x99\xdf!8\xd0G\x14\0\0\0\x35\x93\xeb\xcb\xa9\x16\xadXI\xe6\x46wY\x7f\x32\xb8\xd9\xec\xfb*"
```

I would like to do

```
std::string data = convert(dataID);
```

where convert is a pure c++ function

Comment: You want to take data serialized by Qt and deserialize it without Qt? Why serialize it with Qt in the first place?

Comment: @ildjarn Probably a non-Qt application needs access to something saved by Qt application, and likely without being able to change that other application. Agus - you have access to the source file for QSettings, so you could always check to see how it is decoded internally there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know how to determine the code and how decodec?

Yes, you can do it. [Read this document](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/datastreamformat.html).

Keep in mind that QT stores string data in datastream in UTF16 encoding, and std::string stores 8bit strings. So you'll either need some encoding conversion routines (UTF16->8bit) or just drop every character that isn't in ASCII.